# External CSS isn't applied or overwritten

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to design a webpage somewhat similar in appearance to Microsoft's. (https://www.microsoft.com)
This includes building a image slideshow, which is why I looked up W3 Schools and found this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp This is a great example and when writing all of my code in one html document it works, however, as I try to link to an external stylesheet it doesn't work anymore. I could alternatively founder on the js link but I don't think so, as switching to the next picture works. I searched stackoverflow for it already and people suggested adding ?v3 (or sth. like that) to the link, clearing my cache and so on. - so far nothing worked for my. I tried this in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's how I link to my CSS: (it's in the head)

```
<style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new theme.css">
</style>
```

Here's the js link: (at the end of the body)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/new script.js?v=3"></script>
```

Any ideas why this could be? Maybe some other tutorials for this?
I'll include pictures of the working html which's got everything stuffed in it and one of the html with external js and CSS.

Thank you very much!

[external - not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJ6L.jpg)

[internal - working like a charm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdGJz.jpg)

THANKS EVERYONE! - Simple spelling mistake! Sorry to bother you!

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to discover any errors, and where it is looking for the file(s). Spaces in the filenames should also be avoided.

Comment: Oh, and you don't put link tags in a style element!? The style tag is where you would include your internal stylesheet rules.

Comment: You should not include the <link> inside the style tag. It should be inside the <head> tag. Also when you have file names with spaces in between, you need to encode the name. Ex. `new theme.css` becomes `new%20theme.css`

Comment: @AndyG There are no errors except the missing logo which I moved to another position and haven't redirected to yet. How can I see where it's trying to fetch the files from?

Deleted the style tags, thank you, but that didn't change a thing :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is invalid :

```
<style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new theme.css">
</style>
```

Between `<style>` and `</style>`, there must be CSS code. However `link` is not CSS code, that's an HTML tag. The correct syntax is just :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new theme.css">
```

Then, `"new theme.css"` has a space in its name, so it will likely be encoded to `"new%20theme.css"` and you'll get a 404. Don't use spaces within file names.

Finally, open your console to see any errors, especially to check if the CSS file is being fetched successfully.

Comment: I deleted teh style tags already, thank you! i didn't try deleting the space so far, give me a sec. How or rather where would I see if it fetches the right files?

Edit: Oh and Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I renamed the files, sadly this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any spaces in the names of the files, try using new_theme.css and new_script.js

Answer (score 0):

Reference your CSS like this at the top of your HTML - inbetween the `<head>` tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new_theme.css">
```

Also always try either Camel Case - "newTheme.css" or use an underscore "new_theme.css" when naming your files!

That should fix your problem! :)

Comment: What do you mean by in between the tags? I put it between my <head> tags.

Looks like this atm:

`<head>
 <title>Das Cottage</title>
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newTheme.css"> 
</head>`

Comment: So you have it like:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new_theme.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
//things
</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the  inside the style tag. 
It should be inside the  tag. 
Ex.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new%20theme.css">
<head>
```

Also when you have file names with spaces in between, you need to encode the name. 
Example

`href="new theme.css"`

becomes

`href="new%20theme.css"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newtheme.css">
```

or

```
 <style type="text/css">
   css code here
 </style>
```

open your console to see if it could find your css file